# ThreadPoolExecutor fixed thread pool with custom behaviour

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

i'm new to this topic ... i'm using a ThreadPoolExecutor created with Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 ) and after the pool is full i'm starting to get a RejectedExecutionException .
Is there a way to "force" the executor to put the new task in a "wait" status instead of rejecting it and starting it when the pool is freed ?

Thanks

Issue regarding this 
https://github.com/evilsocket/dsploit/issues/159

Line of code involved https://github.com/evilsocket/dsploit/blob/master/src/it/evilsocket/dsploit/net/NetworkDiscovery.java#L150

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);` it queues the tasks and they wait until a thread is ready.

This method is

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

As you can see, the queue used is unbounded (which can be a problem in itself) but it means the queue will never fill and you will never get a rejection.

BTW: If you have CPU bound tasks, an optimal number of threads can be

```
int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processors);
```

---

A test class which might illustrate the situation

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000; i++)
        es.submit(new SleepOneSecond());

    System.out.println("Queue length " + ((ThreadPoolExecutor) es).getQueue().size());
    es.shutdown();
    System.out.println("After shutdown");
    try {
        es.submit(new SleepOneSecond());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}

static class SleepOneSecond implements Callable<Void> {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return null;
    }
}
```

prints

```
Queue length 999998
After shutdown
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@e026161 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@3e472e76[Shutting down, pool size = 2, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 999998, completed tasks = 0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2013)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:816)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1337)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:132)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Comment: still, i'm getting the RejectedExecutionException as you can see here https://github.com/evilsocket/dsploit/issues/159

Comment: this is the line of code giving the issue https://github.com/evilsocket/dsploit/blob/master/src/it/evilsocket/dsploit/net/NetworkDiscovery.java#L150

Comment: @SimoneMargaritelli the only reason you should get a `RejectedExecutionException` when using a `newFixedThreadPool` would be if you are trying to submit tasks to the executor after its `shutdown` method has been called.

Comment: Given the pool has only ever run 31 tasks, I suspect its not full. Also the corePoolSize is 0 suggesting it has been shutdown which will trigger a rejection.

Comment: @SimoneMargaritelli BTW You don't need to cast to ThreadPoolExecutor, I would leave it as the interface ExecutorService.

Answer (score 4):

It is very possible that a thread calls `exit`, which sets `mStopped` to false and shutdowns the executor, but:

- your running thread might be in the middle of the `while (!mStopped)` loop and tries to submit a task to the executor which has been shutdown by `exit`
- the condition in the `while` returns true because the change made to `mStopped` is not visible (you don't use any form of synchronization around that flag).

I would suggest:

- make `mStopped` volatile
- handle the case where the executor is shutdown while you are in the middle of the loop (for example by catching RejectedExecutionException, or probably better: shutdown your executor after your while loop instead of shutting it down in your exit method).

Answer (score 3):

Building on earlier suggestions, you can use a blocking queue to construct a fixed size `ThreadPoolExecutor`. If you then supply your own `RejectedExecutionHandler` which adds tasks to the blocking queue, it will behave as described.

Here's an example of how you could construct such an executor:

```
int corePoolSize    = 10;
int maximumPoolSize = 10;
int keepAliveTime   =  0;
int maxWaitingTasks = 10;

ThreadPoolExecutor blockingThreadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize,
        keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(maxWaitingTasks),
        new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
                try {
                    executor.getQueue().put(r);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while submitting task", e);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have your ThreadPool created with fixed number of threads but you might have more tasked to be submitted to the thread pool. I would calcuate the keepAliveTime based on the request and set it dynamically. That way you would not have RejectedExecutionException.

For example

long keepAliveTime = ((applications.size() * 60) / FIXED_NUM_OF_THREADS) * 1000;
threadPoolExecutor.setKeepAliveTime(keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

where application is a collection of task that could be different every time.

That should solve your problem if you know average time the task take.